# Change index to date/time type in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I made DataFrame from sqlite3 database with

```
df = sql.read_frame("SELECT * FROM hzmo_report;", cnx, index_col='datum')
```

**print df.dtypes** -> givers me:

```
id                   int64
osiguranika          int64
korisnika            int64
omjer              float64
mirovina           float64
udio               float64
neto_placa           int64
neto_datum          object
sredstva             int64
dzd_korisnika        int64
dzd_djece            int64
dzd_sredstva_sr    float64
dzd_sredstva_bz    float64
dzd_isplata          int64
url                 object
```

Value of id, what was named 'datum' in data base is:

```
print df.index
Index([2012-12-01, 2013-01-01, 2012-11-01, 2013-02-01, 2012-09-01, 2012-10-01, 2012-08-01, 2012-07-01, 2012-06-01, 2012-05-01, 2012-04-01, 2012-03-01, 2012-02-01, 2011-12-01, 2011-11-01, 2011-10-01, 2011-09-01, 2011-08-01, 2011-07-01, 2011-06-01, 2011-05-01, 2011-04-01, 2011-03-01, 2012-01-01, 2011-02-01, 2011-01-01, 2010-12-01, 2010-11-01, 2010-10-01, 2010-09-01, 2010-08-01, 2010-07-01, 2010-06-01, 2010-05-01, 2010-04-01, 2010-03-01, 2010-02-01, 2010-01-01, 2009-12-01, 2009-10-01, 2009-11-01, 2013-03-01], dtype=object)
```

So how to change id(index) from int64 type to some date/time type ?

I wont to do that so that id will be sorted.

Also how to remove date from index, because I have only one entry per mouth so frequency should be monthly. eg. 2012-12-01 to 2012-12 and so on.

**UPDATE:**

When you are constructing DataFrame from SQL database never use SQL query without ORDER BY "your date column"

This is important, because otherwise, your DataFrame will not be ordered by your date column.

so my SQL

```
 df = sql.read_frame("SELECT * FROM hzmo_report;", cnx, index_col='datum')
```

should be:

```
df = sql.read_frame("SELECT * FROM hzmo_report ORDER BY datum;", cnx, index_col='datum')
```

Comment: I have found out that with `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` I can convert to DatetimeIndex.       Only question left is how to set frequency to 1 month ?

Comment: I also found one more big BUG in my code, it is in SQL query. Reason why my row are not sorted by date is duo to SQL query, I use `SELECT * FROM hzmo_report;` but this will not sort by rows by date I had to use `SELECT * FROM hzmo_report ORDER BY datum;`. Now my row are sorted by date.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `pandas.PeriodIndex(df.index, freq='M')`

Comment: Then I have following error: `AttributeError: can't set attribute` in     `427 
    428     base, mult = _gfc(freq)
--> 429     return tslib.dt64arr_to_periodarr(data.view('i8'), base, tz)
    430 
    431 # --- Period index sketch`